# How can I write FPS showing code in YOLOv5

Tags: python, yolov5

I just started to learn YOLOv5. When I write --source 0 in cmd and see myself in the screen I got very excited. I want to add a FPS showing code. I searched it on the internet. I find a code that shows FPS on webcam but I couldn't make them work together with YOLOv5. How should I put this code in Yolo?

The code that showing FPS:

```
webcam_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps_cap_start_time = 0
fps_cap=0

while True:
    rec, frame = webcam_cap.read()

    fps_cap_end_time = time.time()
    time_diff = fps_cap_end_time - fps_cap_start_time
    fps_cap = 1/(time_diff)
    fps_cap_start_time = fps_cap_end_time

    fps_text = "FPS:  {:.2f}".format(fps_cap)

    cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("webcam_cap",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == 81 or key == 113:
        break
webcam_cap.release()
print('code complete')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the time module to keep track of the FPS.

```
from time import time
```

and create a global variable called loop_time which will grab the current time

```
loop_time = time()
```

Then in your while loop you can print the FPS using the following:

```
while True:
if time() - loop_time > 0:
    print('FPS: {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
loop_time = time()
```

The output should look something like: "FPS: 999.1195807527394".

In your code it should look something like

```
webcam_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

loop_time = time()

while True:
    rec, frame = webcam_cap.read()

    fps_text = 1/(time() - loop_time)
    print('FPS: {}'.format(fps_text)
    loop_time = time()

    cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("webcam_cap",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == 81 or key == 113:
        break
webcam_cap.release()
print('code complete')
```